# React returns a null element and I can't find out why

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm just learning the very basics of React, and I'm in trouble to execute the following code, that you may give me a hint to run it properly.

What I'm trying to do is to render a div into the root element, and once it's clicked the display property should toggle. This is done by the 'dissappear' function.

```js
const JSX = (
  <div id="myDiv" className = "myDiv">
    <h1>Add a class to this div</h1>
  </div>
);

const dissappear = (element) => {
element.style.display==="none" ? element.style.display==="block" : element.style.display==="none"
}


ReactDOM.render(JSX, document.getElementById("root"))

let myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
myDiv.onclick = dissappear(myDiv)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id='root'>
</div>
```

---

**EDIT**: as suggested I'm now calling the function after rendering the elements in the page.

Comment: And that reported syntax error would be ... ??

Comment: just updated @Pointy

Comment: when you set the `.onclick` you're **calling** the function, and probably getting an error because `myDiv` doesn't exist.

Comment: You are calling the disappear function before even rendering the JSX in DOM.

Comment: You should read up more on how to handle events with React: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: Plus you must use react events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not how you handle a click event in React:

```
let myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
myDiv.onclick = dissappear(myDiv);
```

For a couple reasons:

1. The element doesn't exist yet, because nothing has been rendered yet when you call this.
2. You're *calling* `disappear` here, and settings its *result* (which is `undefined` because it doesn't return anything) as the click handler.  So the function itself is only invoked once, not set as a click handler.  (This is true for JavaScript in general, not just React.)
3. It's simply not idiomatic React.

Side note: You also have a logical error in your `dissappear` function.  The *first* use of `===` is fine for comparison, but then remaining uses should be `=` for assignment.

Instead, set the `onclick` handler [in the React JSX element itself](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html), and reference the target of the event passed to that handler:

```
const dissappear = (e) => {
  e.target.style.display==="none" ? e.target.style.display="block" : 
  e.target.style.display="none";
};

const JSX = (
  <div id="myDiv" className="myDiv" onClick={dissappear}>
    <h1>Add a class to this div</h1>
  </div>
);
```

For example:

```js
const dissappear = (e) => {
  e.target.style.display==="none" ? e.target.style.display="block" : 
  e.target.style.display="none";
};

const JSX = (
  <div id="myDiv" className="myDiv" onClick={dissappear}>
    <h1>Add a class to this div</h1>
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(JSX, document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'></div>
```

Comment: Why nothing has been rendered if I call it after the render statement? Thanks for the logical error, and for the detailed answer!

Comment: When writing js, I've always tried to avoid put the onclick method, cause I don't like to clutter the html with that, but I guess there is no way around in reacjs?

Comment: @misternobody: Generally the problem solved by separating the HTML and JavaScript (and thus avoiding `onclick`) isn't an issue in React, since the JavaScript and JSX are all together anyway.

Comment: Oh, I see. You mean I can still write a separate .js file using normal functions, isn't it? Sorry I can't up-vote yet...

Comment: @misternobody: You can certainly organize the JavaScript code into multiple files.  Usually in React apps you would include other files with JavaScript's import/export functionality.  This can be useful for breaking out generic business logic into JavaScript classes which don't use React, so they could potentially be re-used in other applications regardless of the framework.  The React code would be entirely UI-based and can invoke that business logic and interact with the JSX.